# Give a deterministic finite complete automaton M for this language, explain the meaning of its states and prove that M accepts exactly the words of L

Tags: algorithms

I have the following Problem:

Language L consists of words over alphabet Σ={0,1} that satisfy the following property: if the word contains 00, then it also contains 11, as well. (For example, 01101000101; 1110; 1010; ε are words of L, but 101001 is not contained in L.) Give a deterministic finite complete automaton M for this language (that is L = L(M)), explain the meaning of its states and prove that M accepts exactly the words of L.

Can anybody help me solve it, please? and thanks in advance I highly appreciate it.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Where is this question from? I am voting to close this question due to lack of context.

Comment: This is a Theory of Algorithms problem, I could not try anything because I do not know how to deal with it, that's why I am asking for help.

Comment: Viktor Glombik if you are unable to help, please ignore this post and let other capable and clever people help. People like you who obstruct improvement and development.

Comment: Please see [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/545914) on how to ask a good question on this page.

Comment: Viktor Glombik Ok Thank you